# ResolverFn in Angula 17

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, backend

idk what is happening, but call a function in the ResolveFn and it calls that the method is not a function

Resolver

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ResolveFn } from '@angular/router';
import { Livro } from '../models/livro';
import { LivrosService } from '../services/livros.service';

export const livrosResolver: ResolveFn<Livro> = (route, state) => {

  if(route.params?.['id']){
    return Inject(LivrosService).loadById(route.params['id'])
  }

  return of({_id: Number(null), name: '', desc: ''});
};
```

Services

```
import { Livro } from './../models/livro';
import { tap, first } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LivrosService {

  private readonly API = 'api/livros'

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,

    ) {
  }

  list(){
    return this.httpClient.get<Livro[]>(this.API)
    .pipe(
      first(),
      tap(formulas => console.log(formulas))
      )
    }

  loadById(id: number){
    return this.httpClient.get<Livro>(`${this.API}/${id}`)
  }

  save(livro: Partial<Livro>){
    return this.httpClient.post<Livro>(this.API, livro);
  }


}
```

Model

```
export interface Livro {
    _id: number;
    name: string;
    desc: string;
}
```

Routing Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LivrosComponent } from './containers/livros/livros.component';
import { LivroFormComponent } from './containers/livro-form/livro-form.component';
import { livrosResolver } from './guards/livros.resolver';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LivrosComponent},
  { path: 'new', component: LivroFormComponent, resolve: {livro:livrosResolver}},
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: LivroFormComponent, resolve: {livro:livrosResolver}}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LivrosRoutingModule { }
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LivrosService } from '../../services/livros.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ErrorDialogComponent } from '../../../shared/components/error-dialog/error-dialog.component';
import { Livro } from '../../models/livro';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-livros',
  templateUrl: './livros.component.html',
  styleUrl: './livros.component.scss'
})
export class LivrosComponent {

  livros$: Observable<Livro[]>

    constructor(
      private livrosServices: LivrosService,
      public dialog: MatDialog,
      private router: Router,
      private route: ActivatedRoute

    )

    {
      this.livros$ = this.livrosServices.list()
    .pipe(
      catchError(error =>{
        this.onError('Erro ao carregar as Fórmulas')
        return of([])
      })
      )
    }

    onError(errorMsg: string) {
      this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
        data: errorMsg
      });
    }


    onAdd(){
      this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route})
    }

    onEdit(livro: Livro){

      this.router.navigate(['edit', livro._id], {relativeTo: this.route})
    }


}
```

The Error

```
ERROR TypeError: Inject(...).loadById is not a function
    at livrosResolver (livros.resolver.ts:10:34)
    at resolve_data.ts:109:42
    at R3Injector.runInContext (r3_injector.ts:235:14)
    at getResolver (resolve_data.ts:109:23)
    at resolve_data.ts:92:18
    at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.ts:71:15)
    at outerNext (mergeInternals.ts:53:58)
    at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.ts:70:13)
    at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.ts:75:12)
    at Observable2._subscribe (innerFrom.ts:78:18)
```

For me using a resolver is a better method to get this data from the Server. But i don't know why this won't work, i do what they explain in the documentation and simply don't work

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `inject(LivrosService)` and not `Inject(LivrosService)`.

Capital [`Inject`](https://angular.io/api/core/Inject) is a decorator.